# Angular won't recognize new component

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and i am creating my first app tour of heroes(everyone does). But the problem is that angular won't recognize new component. Like it isn't giving any error rather not rendering in the browser

**Update:** Ok i have ng serve my application again just like Wahab Shah but this time from VS code terminal instead of Windows terminal and its working now. Thanks alot for the help

**heroes.component.html**

```
<h2>{{hero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
    <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
  </label>
</div>
```

**heroes.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**hero.ts**

```
export interface Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: Have you just created the new component?

Comment: Yup from terminal through command "ng generate component heroes"

Comment: Can you share your code? It is not possible to answer without code

Comment: ng serve your app again, or use the selector of your newly created component inside its parent if thats the case. Can you paste your code snippet? We will be able to better assist you that way.

Comment: Have you declared the component in a module?

Comment: Code snippet pasted

Comment: Update: Ok i have ng serve my application again just like Wahab Shah said but this time from VS code terminal instead of Windows terminal and its working now. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: That's great then. I am posting it as an answer. Just mark it done so if any one else comes to this post can find it helpful.

Comment: That's great then. I am posting it as an answer. Just mark it done so if any one else comes to this post can find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng serve your app again, or use the selector of your newly created component inside its parent if that's the case.

Mostly after adding new component or modules app doesn't render it. Just re serving it can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that,

1. you haven't declared any routes for that component
2. you haven't added the app-selector of that new component in the app.component.html page.

Either of those might result in that new component not rendering in the browser.

Comment: You restart your angular application like one of the comments suggested. Also press F12 and watch if any errors show up in the console

Comment: Did that and its working. The issue was that i was compiling my app from windows terminal. Now that i am doing it from VS code terminal, its working fine. Seems weird though